# How to run properly GitHub Action for Flutter

Tags: flutter, github-actions

I have the following CI configuration file:

```
name: Flutter CI

on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["master"]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}/mobile_app

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: "stable"
      - run: flutter --version

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Run tests
        run: flutter test --coverage

      - name: Analyze project source
        run: flutter analyze --no-fatal-infos --no-fatal-warnings
        continue-on-error: true
```

But an error occurs during operation:

`test/api_test.dart:2:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/utils/api.dart': No such file or directory import 'package:mobile_app/utils/api.dart';` and so on to the whole test files.

It seems the action couldn't see these files, although if I move them out of the **utils** folder into the **lib** it works.

Imports in the api_test.dart are:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mobile_app/utils/api.dart';
```

I've tried changing the imports, but didn't have a success

Comment: Check current directory and its contents with `pwd && ls -l` before running tests.

Comment: @Azeem files from the mobile directory, as should be. There are lib, test, pubspec.yml, and so on.

Comment: Right. Please comment `working-directory` and test again.

Comment: @Azeem, it sees mobile_app folder(_drwxr-xr-x 10 runner docker 4096 Apr 28 14:08 mobile_app_). In the test part, there is the error: "Test directory "test" not found.".

Comment: But, the `test` directory is there, rigth? How do you run these tests locally? From the root of your project?

Comment: @Azeem, not from the root, from the `mobile_app`

Comment: Can you please add you your directory structure is?

Comment: @MinkeshJain, I have already changed the structure, so the problem is no longer relevant.